# Does very short TTL in Cassandra data lead to performance problems?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ttl

For our real high traffic site we've set up a own tracking solution. We log >1k impressions per second in peak. For that we're using latest Cassandra 3.

Now we want to set up a real time monitoring on this data. The problem is, that the actually logged data is not structured well for generating statistics from it. So I thought about a new table in Cassandra which has a matching partition/primary key and that is filled by an additional `INSERT`. But I'm not sure if this is a killer for Cassandra. As I've said, only live statistics are important, so I want to add a TTL of, let's say 60 seconds to all data in this monitoring table. This should ensure that old data is deleted automatically.

But can anyone say if this leads to problems with this high traffic, because there where so many deletions per minute? As we select only last 5-10 seconds from this monitoring table, the tombstone may not be a problem in `SELECT`, but I assume there could be massive compactions and GC that ruin the performance!?

Comment: Why do you need such a small TTL? Can't you keep the info for 1day, for instance? Also, you will have compactions anyway, since you're inserting a lot in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apparently it would.

Having a short TTL means introducing too many tombstone in your system which may result in:

1.query abortion

2.out of memory and heap pressure

3.Latency

in such case you should run compaction very frequently to evict out tombstone from system but this also comes with cons of resource, space consuming and can cause high IO.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the difference between a TTL of 60 seconds and one year? If the traffic is that high constantly, I cannot see a difference except, that the cluster grows over time if TTL is one year. If Cassandra has to cleanup the 1000 impressions which occur just right now in 60 seconds or in one year makes no difference in workload, except that compaction for a huge cluster which holds data for one year may be a bit more expensive. Am I right? With a TTL of one year you just delay the workload that would happen in one minute with a TTL of 60 seconds.